# parse server deploying to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I am trying to deploy deploy my parse server, parse server dashboard, etc to aws. I am sure that the problem that I am experiencing is quite simple and it has to do with how I am packaging my ab node apps. I am downloading the git repo and then uploading the zip to my eb instance. It is in turn giving me this error.

[image]

After downloading a repository, such as parse server, what do I need to do to put it on elastic bean stalk? I already have the parse server example running on aws. I am just trying to upgrade versions.

here is my package.JSON file

```
{
  "name": "parse-server",
  "version": "2.2.16",
  "description": "An express module providing a Parse-compatible API server",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin/",
    "src/",
    "public_html/",
    "views/",
    "LICENSE",
    "PATENTS",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.6.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "commander": "2.9.0",
    "deepcopy": "0.6.3",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "intersect": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.12.0",
    "lru-cache": "4.0.1",
    "mailgun-js": "0.7.10",
    "mime": "1.3.4",
    "mongodb": "2.1.18",
    "multer": "1.1.0",
    "parse": "1.9.0",
    "parse-server-fs-adapter": "1.0.0",
    "parse-server-push-adapter": "1.0.4",
    "parse-server-s3-adapter": "1.0.4",
    "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter": "1.0.0",
    "pg-promise": "5.2.0",
    "redis": "2.6.2",
    "request": "2.73.0",
    "request-promise": "4.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.2.0",
    "tv4": "1.2.7",
    "winston": "2.2.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "1.1.5",
    "ws": "1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-istanbul": "0.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.8.0",
    "codecov": "1.0.1",
    "cross-env": "2.0.0",
    "deep-diff": "0.3.4",
    "gaze": "1.1.0",
    "jasmine": "2.4.1",
    "mongodb-runner": "3.3.2",
    "nodemon": "1.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run build && node bin/dev",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src/ -d lib/",
    "pretest": "cross-env MONGODB_VERSION=${MONGODB_VERSION:=3.2.6} MONGODB_STORAGE_ENGINE=mmapv1 ./node_modules/.bin/mongodb-runner start",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test TESTING=1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node $COVERAGE_OPTION ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js",
    "test:win": "npm run pretest && cross-env NODE_ENV=test TESTING=1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/babel-istanbul/lib/cli.js cover -x **/spec/** ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js && npm run posttest",
    "posttest": "./node_modules/.bin/mongodb-runner stop",
    "coverage": "cross-env COVERAGE_OPTION='./node_modules/babel-istanbul/lib/cli.js cover -x **/spec/**' npm test",
    "start": "node ./bin/parse-server",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.3"
  },
  "bin": {
    "parse-server": "./bin/parse-server"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to physically go into the repository and compress it into a new zip file. For some reason it would not accept zip files that I downloaded off of github.